# Car music getting feedback from fans on amplifier

Tags: audio

I installed 4 fans on my amplifier for cooling purposes, it works great but whenever i press the gas pedal, the whirring sound happens once the fan is on. it emanates from the speaker, its some feedback i guess, how do i get rid of that

Answer (score 2):

That's called "alternator whine" (google it). There are many ways to deal with it. The easiest is to install an inline filter.

[Here](http://www.crutchfield.com/S-BiDp6UPiaCv/learn/learningcenter/car/noise_suppressors_installation_guide.html) is a nice guide to available commercial solutions.